# autocomplete в chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

у меня появилась проблема. И её суть в том что у формы есть анимация при valid и focus но при загрузки страницы появляется автозаполнение и оно мешает, но мне надо не убрать autocomplete а его отследить и , что бы когда он появляется срабатывала анимация.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").on('blur keyup change click', function () {});
```